# What does the Chinese text on this card say?

Tags: simplified-characters

What does the Chinese text on the card say?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sc92.jpg)

Comment: Emmmm，They are two sex positions.

Comment: ouch, I am blind.

Comment: @Jacob 哈哈，中文说就是*闪瞎我的狗眼*。

Answer (score 1):

观音坐莲 (Goddess sitting on lotus leaves)

*观音* ([Guanyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanyin)) *is the Buddhist Goddess of Mercy*

[image: 觀音坐蓮]

老汉推车 (old man pushing cart)

[image: 老漢推車]

Just search Google image and you can find out what kind of sex positions 观音坐莲 and 老汉推车 are

Comment: Omg I can't believe he said that! Thanks guys! Sorry if I've made all of you go blind ‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️

Comment: woman-on-top position & rear-penetration position